# Tiki Wiki CustomSearch destdiv parameter

Tags: tiki-wiki

So I found out using the `destdiv` parameter in the `CustomSearch` causes an infinite fade loading process.

```
{CUSTOMSEARCH( wiki="Custom search 12" id="searchfix" destdiv="displayFirstTabDiv")}
```

I have two tabs on a page each having its own respective `CustomSearch` for tab content, the problem is any search on Tab1 picks content and display on Tab2 instead of Tab1. Tab2 behaves well.

I thought of having `destdiv` to restrict display of Tab1 result to a Div on Tab1 but it goes into an infinite load. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: I think the main issue is having multiple CustomSearch plugin on a page and getting them to behave accordingly.

Comment: Do you have different id's on each one? And is there a div with the id displayFirstTabDiv (and whatever the other one is) on the page?
Is it the same if the searches are not in tabs?
Maybe posting (an edited version of) the whole wiki page source would help, or filing a bug report at https://dev.tiki.org/File+a+bug and then setting up a "show instance" to demonstrate it would help us fix it - thanks

Comment: Yes they both have different ids' and the div with respective ids' are both present on the page. I did try it without the tabs and it gave same result. From testing round it, the issue is having multiple 'CustomSearch' on same page and constraining them to their respective scope just like the 'offset_arg' parameter of 'pagination' enables multiple pagination to co-exist on a single page. Will use the bug report as advised. Thanks